# location.hash is always empty

Tags: javascript, url

I'm trying to get the hash parameters from an url with javascript. The strange thing is that the hash parameter is always empty (""). i have tried many variations of code but it's always empty.

```
location.hash
```

Example url

```
file:///F:/wwwroot/Default.htm#Name=front
```

What is it I'm missing?

Comment: That should work. Can you set up a JS Fiddle to demo the problem?

Comment: what browser do you use? (works for me in Chrome and FF)

Comment: I have tried IE, FF and chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the answer, the javascript code was called on from inside a iframe and appertly they act just like a separate html page. I used this code to solve it.

```
var url = window.parent.location.hash;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think location.hash works pointing to local files. You need to serve your page from a web server. So you would have a url such as `http://localhost:1337/Default.htm#Name=front`